# PostgreSQL query returning zero rows with double precision field/function

Tags: postgresql

I've got:

```
SELECT x(point), y(point) WHERE x(point) = 3.69334468807005
```

x and y are of type double precision.

I see that this value is in the table indeed, however running the query in PostgreSQL does not return anything. Why could that be the case? Maybe due to a precision problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When dealing with floating point numbers (both single or double precision) then doing an exact compare is futile in 99% of all cases. This is true not only for PostgreSQL but for all computer languages using FP arithmetic.

The three reasons are, that the internal representation of a double can contain much more digits than displayed and that at the same time many numbers cannot be expressed exactly using FP (0.1 is an often cited example) and that therefore all "displayed" values are truncated to something a human can comprehend (i.e. nothing like "0.099999999999999999999999999" instead of "0.1").

Therefore it is necessary to to avoid direct comparison as soon as one of the numbers to be compared has been calculated (rounding errors) or has been converted from a string. Instead some "range" must be admitted like

```
where x between 3.69334468807004 and 3.69334468807006 -- note the different numbers
```

The only valid cases for direct comparison are cases where the value has been just copied previously. A fictive example would be:

```
SELECT x, y, f1(x,y), f2(x,y), ... INTO TEMP temp_xy FROM points;
SELECT * FROM points p JOIN temp_xy t on p.x = t.x and p.y = t.y;
```

x and y have been just copied, therefore they can be used as a join criteria.

**Edit** A good starter for this and some more non-intuitive problems with floats is [this article](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/floating_point/understanding_floating_point_representation.html).

Answer (score 3):

Old school answer: "Don't compare floating point numbers solely for equality." (Elements of Programming Style, Kernighan and Plauger, 1978)

Why? Because comparing two floats for equality will always work under certain circumstances, but it will almost never work under slightly different circumstances. That's due to the nature of floating-point numbers, not to programmer skill.

The canonical article for floating-point math is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19422-01/819-3693/ncg_goldberg.html).

In your case, you might be able to adapt [the relative difference function from this C language FAQ](http://c-faq.com/fp/fpequal.html). (Scroll down, look for RelDif().)

Answer (score 2):

You could certainly test if it is a precision problem, just expand the WHERE clause of your statement to be a range, and tighten that range (by adding more precision) until you have your record or can confirm it is related to precision:

```
SELECT x(point), y(point)
WHERE x(point) > 3.69
  AND x(point) < 3.70
```

The other thing I would look at is perhaps using some other form of key when filtering your data. Does your table have some sort of natural key you could use or maybe just add an auto-incremented field for use a primary key?

I have also seen indexes behave badly when functions are involved. Are there any indexes on this table?